# Excel number combination comparison

Tags: excel

I need to compare the sets of numbers on the left (six numbers row) to the ones on the right (six numbers per row). I need to find combinations that are the same; for example, notice that row 1 on the left is the same as row 3 on the right. The program must identify this and highlight on the left set on numbers.

```
LEFT HAND SIDE
2   15  26  27  36  48
1   12  13  15  24  34
3   5   20  28  37  40
RIGHT HAND SIDE
3   15  19  29  39  35
1   2   27  48  24  37
15  2   26  47  27  48
```

Comment: Are the numbers on the left hand side always in ascending order in each row?

Comment: My post highlights the right set of numbers instead of the left - temporarily deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it: combine the numbers (assumed to be a maximum of 2  digits - they look like lottery numbers) in the correct order into a single large number in another column and match on this column. In column G and copied to column N:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(A2:F2,COLUMN(A2:F2)-COLUMN(A2)+1)*100^(COLUMN(A2:F2)-COLUMN(A2)))
```

Then in Conditional Formatting| New Rule | Use a formula :-

```
 =MATCH($G2,$N$2:$N$4,0)
```

If you wish you can also do a reverse lookup on each right-hand set of numbers as shown below.

[image]